# HandGesture Detection

Tags: python, windows, opencv

When I run this:

```
contours,_,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I have also tried:

```
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

and:

```
contours,hierarchy,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HASHMATI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/new2hand.py", line 152, in <module>
    gestureRecognition(frame,roi_rect,frame[y:y+h, x:x+w])
  File "C:/Users/HASHMATI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/new2hand.py", line 99, in gestureRecognition
    detectGesture(src,roi_rect,img_dilated)
  File "C:/Users/HASHMATI/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/new2hand.py", line 21, in detectGesture
    contours,_,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: It's `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`, see the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). Also, the error message tells you, that there are only two return values, or "values to unpack".

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.findContours()` return two values and cannot be unpacked to contours, hierarchy and _

It should be like this：

`contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

or more：

`a, b, *others = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Thanks for reminding，I fixed the answer，but It looks caused by the different version of the opencv, if it is only a  value unpacking issue,  this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference between OpenCV 3.x and 4.x. In 3.x there were three return values, in 4.x there are only two. As the others mentioned, you only catch `contours` and `hierarchy`:

```py
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Alternatively, you can downgrade your OpenCV version, if what you actually want is to use 3.x.